# Android card view collections filtering and sorting

Tags: java, android, user-interface, material-design, android-cardview

[Card View stack with various sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSDYi.png)

I have good understanding on how to use CardViews in a grid-layout fashion. But I would like to develop similar to posted image, where cards are of variable sizes. How do I go about that? Also, how does one filter and sort the cards programmatically, Android documentation is not clear.

Any resource or code snippets will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### The grid

That kind of dynamic lists and grids can be created using `RecyclerView`, no matter what the single item is: `CardView`, `ImageView`, that's your choice.

In the official documentation's you can find some clear and easy examples for creating a basic form of recyclerview https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html.

### Masonry grid

To layout elements in a staggered grid just attach a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to `RecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(/* # of columns */, /* orientation */));
```

### CardViews as items

If you want `CardView`s as items in the `RecyclerView` first of all import the necessary dependencies in app.gradle(Module:app):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Then create the layout file of the single item (i.e. card_item.xml):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- other note contents -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and inflate it in the adapter you previously created:

```
@Override
public NotesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

### Different types of items

In the image you provided notes and statistics are very different: some have images, some text only, some checkboxes... This can be implemented using `RecyclerView` in different ways:

Different types, different views: if items are clearly distinguishable in 2 or more types you can create different item layouts and different `ViewHolder`s:

```
class ViewHolderType1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolderType1(View itemView){
        // ...
    }
}

class ViewHolderType2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolderType2(View itemView){
        // ...
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // The Note class could memorize the type
    return mNotes.get(position).getType();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ViewHolderType1(...);
         case 1: return new ViewHolderType2(...);
     }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch(holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            ViewHolderType1 viewHolder1 = (ViewHolderType1) holder;
            // Here you have access to type specific views
            // to fill with data
            break;
        case 1:
            ViewHolderType2 viewHolder2 = (ViewHolderType2) holder;
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

An alternative could be creating just one type of `CardView` with all possible child views inside and conditionally displaying them with `setVisibility()` depending on the current Note object.
This approach in some cases will leave unused the `View.GONE` views but will probably be a bit more efficient from the recycling point of view.

### Drag to reorder, swipe to dismiss

If by

> filter and sort the cards programmatically

you mean sorting the `ArrayList<>` or other data structure you pass to the `Adapter` you can do it with Java `Collections` or [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) (streams need Java 8 to be [enabled](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)) and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

If you want to give the user the ability to reorder items by dragging or delete by swiping `ItemTouchHelper` makes it simple: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did not know the layout was known as "StaggeredGridLayoutManager" in the API language. This will help me a lot.